# Redirect to subfolder with same name on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a webproject saved in a "base" folder of the domain "example.com" which contains a main.php and several subfolders. **The second part** of the code below **redirects all requests** (except main.php itself and page404.php) **to this main.php and hands over the originally requested URL in the variable "path"**.

**In addition there is a first part which redirects all requests of pages of the baseurl to a subfolder "folder1"**. So in the end the request of

> www.example.com/somepage.php

will lead to

> example.com/main.php?path=www.example.com/**folder1**/somepage.php

(Requests to other subfolders shall only be redirected to the main.php. So `www.example.com/somefolder/somepage.php` will lead to `example.com/main.php?path=www.example.com/somefolder/somepage.php` - without adding "folder1".)

**The code below actually does what I want:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#first part: redirect to folder1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^page404*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php 

#second part: redirect to main.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !main\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page404\.php
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /main.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But I have two questions:

**Side question**: I have the feeling that actually redirecting to "folder1" is way to complicated (even though it works) when I only want to add the "folder1" to the path variable in case a file of the base folder is called. Can you show me a better way to archieve this?

**Main question**: I have the same project on a localhost where the main folder is named "folder1" which contains the folder "folder1". So there the request of *htttp://localhost/folder1/somepage.php* shall lead to *htttp://localhost/folder1/main.php?path=htttp://localhost/folder1/**folder1**/somepage.php* (I replaced "http" by "htttp" to avoid automatic link recognition of SO) - **How do I have to change the code above to have it working in the "localhost/folder1" scenario?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stuff can be simplified:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

# ignore main.php, page404.php OR any files/directory for any rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(main|page404)\.php
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#first part: /folder1/path
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?\.php)$ main.php?path=folder1/$1 [L,QSA]

#second part: rewrite to main.php 
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)$ main.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you very much, this looks much simpler and works to a far degree. Unfortunally there are two problems: **First** is that I had problems until I removed the "/" before "folder1" in the third last row - can you verify this is correct? **Second** is that in my old code the redirect happened also if the original file existed, now e.g. www.example.com/somepage.php will call that page (because the file "somepage.php" exists) - what can I do to ignore those existing files and call example.com/main.php?path=www.example.com/folder1/somepage.php again...?

Comment: ok it is awfully late here to a hurried response, try updated rules now. I will check back tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, the edited version works fine. I just added a RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.php before the last two rewriterules to have the other resources than .php not redirected. Thanks for your late help. Due to your simplifying my "localhost" main problem seems to be solved as well. The first tests looked good and I am confident it will work properly when I look into it again tomorrow - getting late here too ;-)